Is Ukraine allowed to deploy minefields on the Romanian border?
The probably important factors are:

The purpose of the minefield is to prevent civilian population,
escaping conscription,
illegally,
while the country is in war.

Obvious goal is to use the deterring effect of the minefield to decrease the cost of the border control.
Does it violate international law (agreements signed by Ukraine), or not?

@EikePierstorff I see. I do an independent search, if I do not find anything, I will delete the post unless neutral or opposite source does not support it. Btw, doing that would be pretty rational for the ua side.

Usage of antipersonal landmines is prohibited by the Ottawa Treaty, to which Ukraine is a signatory. So Ukraine is not allowed to deploy antipersonal landmines.
Note that much bigger mines like antitank mines are specifically not covered by this treaty.
